# Issues while importing public pgp key though gpg

Tags: gnupg, pgp

BACKGROUND: We had pgp software installed on old servers but on our new servers the infrastructure team installed gpg. So we have to do everything using gpg tool now. I am new to this.

So when we try to import a `PGP` public key block using the gpg import command we get the following error

```
>gpg --import /<filepath>/PGPKey.asc --user xyzzzd
 gpg: Warning: using insecure warning!
 gpg please see http://www.gnupg.org/faq.html for more inoformation
 gpg key 0DBC987k: "zyzzd <pgpadmin@xyprod.#####.com>" not changed
 gpg can't open '--user':No such file or directory
 gpg can't open 'xyzzzd':No such file or directory
 gpg Total number processed: 1
 gpg              unchanged: 1
```

Note we have placed the PGPKey.asc in the temp directory and the commands have been executed from that directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `--user` option in GnuPG, especially not for `--import` which expects all further arguments to be files to be imported; and I could neither find one for PGP.

The message says that the key `0DBC987k` was already successfully imported into the GnuPG keyring, and no files could be found for `--user` nor `xyzzzd`.

Very likely you're fine just removing `--user xyzzzd`, otherwise you'll have to explain in detail what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: hmm, actually we too are not sure what --user does as the command was there in the documentation, maybe it adds user to the key?

Comment: I can see it for other commands (there it adds a user ID), but there is no `--user` for `--import` as far as I can see.